# javascript variables containg jquery api evaluated at calling or assignment time?

Tags: jquery

If i assign a variable something like this

```
var a = $("input").val();
```

At the start of the program.
And then call something like this :

```
$("div").html(a);
```

Will this print the value of the value which was the value in the `input` when the `var a = $("input").val();` was executed or when the line : `$("div").html(a);` was executed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line (`var a = $("input").val();`) sets the value of a variable to whatever data is available. Later on when you use that variable (`a`), it will be the same value. It is only a string, it is not the actual DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

It will print the value that it had when you first assigned it.

Edit: If you want to work with its current value, just evaluate it each time:

```
$("div").html( $("input").val() );
```

Comment: Correct - variables are by value not by reference.

Answer (score 0):

a will contain the value when you first assigned it so the that value will be set in the div html